# MSB6006 "csc.exe" exited with code -1073741819?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Has anyone faced this ... Was working fine a week ago.

Steps I tried:

1. **Re-installed the installer**
2. **Re-installed Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise**
3. **Ran several repairs from the installer**
4. **Clean install.NET 3.1 Framework / .NET 5.0 Framework / VS Framework (basically all the frameworks)**
5. **Delete obj & bin folders and build**
6. **Deleted and installed all packages (installer was failing due to Debuger/Remote package being corrupted)**

[image]

It fails the build every time there I'm trying to get a list by direct index as in the picture below e.g. `wagons[i]`

This is where it says it fails:

[image: This is where it says it fails]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after all a simple check for a windows update, updating and installing with a restart fixed it. As far as I could judge the C# compiler `csc.exe` file was misbehaving.

Could be worth a try if anyone else experiences a similar glitch